# Flask API server slow response time

Tags: gunicorn, flask

I created an API server with Flask, I use `gunicorn` with `eventlet` to run it. I noticed a long response time from Flask server when calling APIs. I did a profiling with my client, one ran from my laptop, one ran directly in Flask API server.

From my laptop:

```
         302556 function calls (295712 primitive calls) in 5.594 seconds                                                              

   Ordered by: internal time                                                                                                          

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)                                                               
       72    4.370    0.061    4.370    0.061 {method 'poll' of 'select.epoll' objects}                                               
       16    0.374    0.023    0.374    0.023 {method 'connect' of '_socket.socket' objects}                                          
       16    0.213    0.013    0.213    0.013 {method 'load_verify_locations' of '_ssl._SSLContext' objects}                          
       16    0.053    0.003    0.058    0.004 httplib.py:798(close)                                                                   
       52    0.034    0.001    0.034    0.001 {method 'do_handshake' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects}
```

On server:

```
        231449 function calls (225936 primitive calls) in 3.320 seconds                                                              

   Ordered by: internal time                                                                                                          

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)                                                               
       12    2.132    0.178    2.132    0.178 {built-in method read}                                                                  
       13    0.286    0.022    0.286    0.022 {method 'poll' of 'select.epoll' objects}                                               
       12    0.119    0.010    0.119    0.010 {_ssl.sslwrap}                                                                          
       12    0.095    0.008    0.095    0.008 {built-in method do_handshake}                                                          
  855/222    0.043    0.000    0.116    0.001 sre_parse.py:379(_parse)                                                                
 1758/218    0.029    0.000    0.090    0.000 sre_compile.py:32(_compile)                                                             
     1013    0.027    0.000    0.041    0.000 sre_compile.py:207(_optimize_charset)                                                   
    12429    0.023    0.000    0.029    0.000 sre_parse.py:182(__next)
```

So, I saw my client took long time to wait from server response base on the profile result.

I used `gunicorn` with `eventlet` to serve Flask app, with the flowing configuration:

```
import multiprocessing

bind         = ['0.0.0.0:8000']
backlog      = 2048
workers      = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
worker_class = 'eventlet'
user         = 'www-data'
group        = 'www-data'
loglevel     = 'info'
```

My client is an custom HTTP client using `eventlet` to patch `httplib2` and create a pool to connect to server.

I stuck here with the troubleshooting. All server stats were normal. How can I detect the bottle neck of my API server?